# Long delay for pdf generation & sending e-mail. Put an image while server parses scripts?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, pdf-generation

I'm working on a form in which you can order courier service. The main idea for it is to generate PDF file containing validated data and then attach it to an e-mail to client + cc for courier company.

The thing is pdf generation (TCPDF) and e-mail sending (Swiftmail) takes noticeably long.

I would like to prevent impatient user from clicking 'confirm' over and over. The ideal solution would be to show some gif 'loading' image or so. I've looked into jquery .load() function and it looks like a good thing for this problem, but what about users w/o js?

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ajax in this case. but if lack of JS is a genuine concern for you, there are couple of ways to do this without JS. 
First you can display something to the user before starting to work with pdf. eg

```
<?php
echo "<html><head></head><body> Please Wait..";
flush();
// process pdf here
?>
```

function flush() will force the webserver to send the data to the browser, so it will be displayed while the rest of the page is loaded. However some browsers will cache this thing internally. There are ways to overcome this (check out comments in php.net for a flush() function) but it could get messy.

Another way is to process PDF asynchronously. In this case target script just displays a message that email will be send shortly. And fires the script witch actually going to send it. eg:

```
<?php
  echo "<html><head></head><body> Email will be send out shortly </body></html>";

  $params='';
  foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
    $params.=$name.'='.$value.'&';
  }
  if ($params!='')
    $params=urldecode(substr($params,0,-1));
  $parts=parse_url('process_pdf.php'.'?'.$params);
  $fp = fsockopen('process_pdf.php',80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
  $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
  $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
  $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($parts['query'])."\r\n";
  $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
  $out.= $parts['query'];
  fwrite($fp, $out);
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

in this example "process_pdf.php" will get all the same POST parameters as original script. but will be executed in the background without interrupting the original page.

Answer (score 1):

More than 98% of users have javascript activated. The remaining 2% is made by:

- Utterly nerdy people who know how to disable it and want to do it: they probably won't click on the submit button as if it was going out of style, since they'll notice the default browser loading indicators;
- People with sight problems, who use screen readers and won't benefit much from the image anyway.

Js is taken mostly for granted nowadays, and it's a web standard. I'd say don't worry and go for it - there is no other way to do it. Still, for the blind, it would be nice to have a `<noscript>` tag with information such as "The operation might take some seconds".

Comment: I like your approach, but unfortunately I can't rely on JS at all in this case, even if it's taken for granted. :) If it wasn't a company site, that has to target all interested people (nerdy too I guess) I'd go for it. Thanks.

Comment: Ivan: there are not a few other ways to display a "loading" image after a click on a submit button. @muchzill: you could still use the `<noscript>` notice for those not using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to do the processing (creating the PDF and sending the email) in a background job. So when your uses clicks 'Confirm', this background job is started with the input from the form and the user is shown a message that his job is being processed and he or she will receive a confirmation by email shortly. This way, you avoid relying on Javascript all together.

You could use something like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) for this.